# Redirect referring page after login and template the profile page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication, profile, referrer

I'm having a wordpress site(still offline) which is basically a news paper site. Users has to registered to comment. My problem is that when users login for commenting on any article, they are redirected to profile page  (or to home page if i use some plugins)... but the standard should be redirecting them to the referring page as to comment on that was the reason they logged in. What is the solution for this?

And another thing is the user profile, my site actually don't need a user profile but need option to change the password. By default the profile is same like the wp dashboard, how do i template it? Is it author.php file that i have to work on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the redirection. You can simply specify the wp login url, where it should take them after they login..
For example.

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Login">Login</a>
```

Takes you to the current page, after the login.. So place a link after the comment.

for disabling profile page modify wp-admin/profile.php like

```
define('IS_PROFILE_PAGE', true);
```

Change to:

```
define('IS_PROFILE_PAGE', false);
```

I hope you can find the wp comments login link easily in template files.

Comment: Can anything be done so the registered user also redirect to the post other than the profilr?

Comment: From where you want to Redirect the registered user ?

Comment: After they register, i want them to be redirected to the home page or the page they where in. Usually they are directed to the profile page.